# Running iOS apps on Apple Silicon leads to permission error

Tags: macos, ios, permission, apple-silicon

I am about to travel and wanted to try to fetch the Netflix app from my phone, following [this tutorial](https://appleinsider.com/articles/20/12/08/how-to-use-ios-apps-on-an-apple-silicon-mac-and-how-to-extract-them-from-your-iphone-or-ipad). When I try to launch an app, I get the error "You do not have permission to open the application ___. Contact your computer or network administrator for assistance":

[image: Netflix App Error]

I tried several existing workarounds for the same message (eg. `sudo chmod -R 755` on the executable), to no avail. Has someone managed to work around this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a limitation of *Apple Configurator 2*. When exporting apps using *iMazing*, apps launch without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for watching Netflix and other on-demand services including YouTube is a dedicated native video browser.
I find the Friendly app in the AppStore (free) to be the best option.

You still need to log into Netflix, but once logged in it behaves just like the Netflix app on iOS, but with the added benefit of PiP, and full-screen support on your full-size screen (at your Netflix subscription resolution).
I use it on an M1 Mac Mini 8GB and it plays well while I use other applications, and hasn’t got any memory leak or other conflicts that I can ascertain.

Adding other services to the built-in list is as easy as adding the relevant URL, and registration details.
Friendly appears to be very well supported by the developer with regular updates.